# pip error trying to install

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I get an error anytime I try to install something with pip, what can I do to fix it? I just installed the latest version with apt-get. This is the error I am getting when I just type pip:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
   load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
   return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
   return ep.load()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
   ['__name__'])
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
   from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
   from pip.download import path_to_url
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
   from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: flask a plugin for beet

Comment: One time I have the same error and I uninstall pip and the python tools and reinstall everything again and the error gone